# How to change font size when printing from Firefox?

Tags: firefox, printing

When printing a page from Firefox I only get a very large font so even the smallest web page needs two or more pages.
Scaling the screen font has proved to be ineffective.
Thus my question.
TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ctrl + P` - Go to `Page Setup` - `Scale`.

[image]

Change scale from 100% to something less, for example 50%.